# Set background image inside div stretch

Tags: html, css, image, stretch

Here is my code:

```css
#mainwrapper {
  font: 10pt normal Arial, sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1000px;
}
/* Image Box Style */

#mainwrapper .box {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}
#mainwrapper .box img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
#mainwrapper .box .caption {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  left: 0;
}
/** Caption 1: Simple **/

#mainwrapper .box .simple-caption {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  bottom: -30px;
  line-height: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
}
/** Simple Caption :hover Behaviour **/

#mainwrapper .box:hover .simple-caption {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="mainwrapper">
  <!-- Image Caption 1 -->
  <div id="box-1" class="box">
    <img id="image-1" src="http://www.sideshowtoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/marvel-deadpool-sixth-scale-hot-toys-feature-902628.jpg" />
    <span class="caption simple-caption">
     <p>Pool</p>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to set background image inside parent div to stretch.

I have tried  in `#mainwrapper .box img` like

```
position:absolute;
margin: auto;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

But it doesn't work .

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ce2nL15h/)

Comment: Am I understanding your question correctly? Or do you want the image to be stretched to fit perfectly inside of the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a few things:

- you can't have `p` tag inside `span`
- use `max-width:100%` in your `img` (or `width:100%` if the image is smaller than the container)
- use `max-width` over `width` in your `#mainwrapper` to avoid scrollbars, with that the container will be "resizable", so easier to work for responsive
- remove `background:cover`, because you don't have a background at all

**UPDATE**

added `object-fit` per OP request in comment.

```css
#mainwrapper {
  font: 10pt normal Arial, sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
/* Image Box Style */

#mainwrapper .box {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}
#mainwrapper .box img {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
#mainwrapper .box .caption {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  left: 0;
}
/** Caption 1: Simple **/

#mainwrapper .box .simple-caption {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  bottom: -30px;
  line-height: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
}
/** Simple Caption :hover Behaviour **/

#mainwrapper .box:hover .simple-caption {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="mainwrapper">
  <!-- Image Caption 1 -->
  <div id="box-1" class="box">
    <img id="image-1" src="http://www.sideshowtoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/marvel-deadpool-sixth-scale-hot-toys-feature-902628.jpg" />
    <span class="caption simple-caption">Pool</span>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div id="box-2" class="box">
    <img id="image-2" src="//lorempixel.com/100/400" />
    <span class="caption simple-caption">Pool</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as I commented in Turner's answer , how can I make it for portrait images ?

Comment: you can use `object-fit`, but IE doesn't support it , [Can I use Object-Fit](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

Comment: Of course , I don't consider it for IE , can you show me an example using Object-Fit ?

Comment: @zey see updated answer with `object-fit` and here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/robinrendle/pen/BywNVX) with all options

Comment: it's simple and perfect @dippas

Answer (score 1):

Just set the image's width to 100%

```
#mainwrapper .box img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ce2nL15h/1/)

Comment: Wow , nice ,that's work for landscape image @Hunter Turner , but how can I stretch for both landscape and portrait ? setting height height 100% for portrait ? I mean for both height and width !

Comment: it's right @Hunter Turner :) , but i have both landscape and portrait images to stretch . Can you show me some example with portrait image too ?

Comment: @zey Like this? **Portrait**: https://jsfiddle.net/ce2nL15h/2/ **Landscape**: https://jsfiddle.net/ce2nL15h/3/

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/ce2nL15h/4/  , i updated it .
you can browse the image, but the image doesn't show fully , it's just like cropping . How can I fix this ?

Comment: That's because it's the max height. Otherwise, there'd be a large white space on the top and bottom. Is that want you want? Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ce2nL15h/5/

Comment: wow , it fix in width , nice , but I don't want a large white space that you mentioned . It's too close to get what I want @HunterTurner :)

Comment: Since you want to see the full image, you have 2 options. You can either stretch the image, which won't look good, or you can have the white space if the image doesn't fit.

Comment: don't worry about image quality @HunterTurner , I just want to stretch the image .

Answer (score 0):

or add the `background-image` in css for the div.

```
.box {
background-image: url("http://www.sideshowtoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/marvel-deadpool-sixth-scale-hot-toys-feature-902628.jpg"); 
background-size:cover;
}
```

remove the `<img>` tag in your HTML if you choose this route.